# Add dynamic project into eclipse

Tags: eclipse, import

I want to add my existing dynamic web project into Eclipse workspace. I tried over google and found some usefuls but still its not done. I know one way is to create a new dynamic project and copy existing src folder and lib folder into new src and lib but the problem is where to keep jsp and vm. Can anyone please tell me how can i import existing dynamic web project into eclipse as i want to enhance it.
Thanx a lot

Comment: What do you mean by "vm"? Is it already a dynamic web project, or it is a pure java project? What is the current form of your project?

Comment: VM files are the template part of velocity, yeah its a dynamic web project and the project is already developed but requires some upgradation and support maintenance. So for each change we needs to perform "ant clean <taregt name>" and tomcat restart. I want to avoid this task again again

Answer (score 0):

```
Open Eclipse, select File > New > Project
Select "Java Project from Existing Ant Build File"
Show your build file and write a project name
```